# Why my reputation decreases by 2 whenever my answer gets upvoted or accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

This is my first question in meta.Since some days I am experiencing a strange problem in my Stackoverflow account.For example, if my answer gets up voted, I should get 10 reputations. Instead my reputation increases by 8 only. Similarly if my answer is accepted I should get 15, but it increase by 13 only.To confirm if I get down voted, I clicked on `View upvote and downvote totals` ,I didn't find any down votes.Also there is no down vote instance in the reputation summary of my profile.

**EDIT:** yesterday my reputation was 2087 and today I got one of my answer accepted as well as up voted. So my reputation should increase to 2112 but its 2110.

Is there any specific reason for it which I am not aware of ?

Comment: I don't see any case of earning 8 or 13 reputation on your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1665507/spring-breaker?tab=reputation&sort=time). Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Unfortunately I didn't take any screenshot because my reputation summary shows I got 25 reputation for that answer not 13 where as on total I got only 13 increased.

Comment: It happens whenever you got some downvote, let say `-2` rep and you get some upvote so it will show increment of `+8`. From your profile I can see that downvote is removed by some downvoter so now it will show exact `+10`.

Comment: @Log1c: But I can't see any down vote summary in my profile and also as per my edited question, it only increased by 13 not 15 still.

Comment: Check the "show deleted posts" box on your rep history and you'll almost certainly see where the 2 rep went.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [Wooble](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble)'s comment, I found out where those 2 rep went. Actually the original author of the question had deleted the question from where I had gotten 2 rep by editing it. Coincidentally at the time when my answer was up voted, those questions are deleted.

You can see it by clicking on the `show removed posts` which you can find in the below part under reputation tab of your profile. See the below image for clarification,

[image]